# Do I need to find odd ratio for the result of binomial GLMM?

Tags: binomial-distribution, glmm

I have run a binomial generalised linear mixed model (GLMM) via the lme4 package in R. Then I have got the result for it. In the paper, I wrote this for the result: b = 2.23, SE = 0.59, p < 0.01.
However, I'm not sure if I need to find odd ratio for this? If yes, can you please tell me how to do it in R. And how I should add the odd ratio result in the finding?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should report the odds ratio, logits are often difficult to interpret. It's been awhile since I've done one but try (with glmer loaded) either A or B.

A.)

fixed <- fixef(ModelName)

confintfixed <- confint(ModelName, parm = "beta_", method = "Wald")

OR <- exp(cbind(fixed, confintfixed))

OR

B.)

parameters::parameters(ModelName, exponentiate = TRUE, details = TRUE)

Other info below

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lme4/versions/1.1-31/topics/glmer

^glmer package link

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sjPlot/vignettes/plot_model_estimates.html

^ cool way to visualize odds

Comment: Hi Nick, the optimal model of mine is the one with three-way interaction. I've run emmeans function. Then it gives me the p-value of each pair of contrasts: for example, ao clear dm - av con no    -3.2262 0.595 Inf  -5.425  <.0001 / However, when I run the formula you've given me, the odd ratios are not for each pair of contrasts. So I can't add the odd ratio to the p-value. What should I do then? Is there the way to find odd ratio for each contrast for the three-way interaction model?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, I'd need a bit more information. Do you have the output from the syntax above? Can you screen shot it so I can see what your saying?

Comment: Sure. Please see above.

Answer (score 0):

The optimal model of mine is from this syntax:
fm1 <- glmer (answer~ (1|subj) + (1|item) + see*conversation*mask, data=analysis1, family=binomial, control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa",optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5)))

So I have three variables. They're all categorical. The first variable has two categories; the second one has two categories and the last one has three caetegories. The optimal model is the model with three-way interaction which means all variables are needed to explain the finding.

And this is the output I've got from emmeans package to see if there are significant differences in each contrast:

[image]

The example of my interpretations is 'The participants received significantly lower score in ao, clear, dm context than ao, con, dm context (b = -4.74, SE = 0.60, p < 0.01).'

However, after running your syntax, it gives me this:

[image]

So now I wondered how the output from OR syntax fits with the comparisons of each pair contrast. Could you please suggest me about this?